# Conditional Average Treatment Effects: What is the logic underlying using the covariates to predict the residualized scores?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, causality

I've consulted a few references, including [this online book](https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/22-Debiased-Orthogonal-Machine-Learning.html), and I've got a good grasp on using double machine learning to estimate ATE after debiasing/denoising the treatment variable (**T**) and the target variable of interest (**y**). In a nutshell, some ML algorithm uses a set of nuisance covariates to predict both **T** and **y**, and the prediction error is used to compute the residualized scores, **T_res** and **y_res**. With the variance among these scores attributable to the covariates removed, we can get an unbiased estimate of the parameter describing the causal relationship between **T** and **y**.

Applications of double-ML to estimate conditional average treatment effects (CATE) puzzle me, however. Here, we construct a model in which we use the interaction between **T_res** and the covariates to predict **y_res**, as in the following code snippet:

```
cate_model = smf.ols(formula='Y_res ~ T_res * (cov_1 + cov_2)', data = train_df).fit()

CATE = cate_model.predict(test_df.assign(T_res=1))
     - cate_model.predict(test_df.assign(T_res=0)))
```

By definition, **cov_1** and **cov_2** do not predict **Y_res**, and if a linear regression was performed after normalization, their associated coefficients should *theoretically* be zero (they won't be exactly zero, but they will be non-significant, and the CI includes zero).

Is there an explanation for why the covariates have any utility in predicting **y_res** in the CATE model? I understand that, without these covariates, the prediction for all individuals would just be the ATE, but I don't understand why the variability among predictions introduced by the interaction with the covariates isn't just attributed to error.